# Make xjc generate class with member variable names exactly same as element names

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc, xjb

Is there a way to specify in external binding that the member variable names in generated classes should follow the same letter case (and not the java conventions), on a schema level (i.e. not a globalbinding)?

I am having elements named as **XYZProperty** in the schema, which should have corresponding member variable named as **XYZProperty** itself and not **xyzProperty**. I tried adding the following in the binding file, but it didn't work:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='SomeType']/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='XYZProperty']">
    <jxb:property name="XYZProperty"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

where **//xsd:complexType[@name='SomeType']/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='XYZProperty']** is the xpath to the element in the schema.

Answer (score 1):

OpenJDK implementation of xjc uses `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.impl.NameConverter#toVariableName` to convert property name to member variable name. It seems that there is no implementation that can leave variable name 'as is'. If it is applicable you can write your [own xjc plugin](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/developPlugins.html), that will set private property name to its public name. Plugin may be like this:

```
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.sun.tools.xjc.Options;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.model.CClassInfo;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.model.CPropertyInfo;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.outline.Outline;

public class XJCPlugin extends Plugin {
    @Override
    public String getOptionName() {
        return "XsameElementNames";
    }

    @Override
    public int parseArgument(Options opt, String[] args, int i) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsage() {
        return "  -XsameElementNames    :  set property private name as its public name";
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessModel(Model model, ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        for (CClassInfo c : model.beans().values()) {
            for (CPropertyInfo prop : c.getProperties()) {
                prop.setName(false, prop.getName(true));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean run(Outline arg0, Options arg1, ErrorHandler arg2) throws SAXException {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But I don't think that I can have my own implementation used in the existing project. Only now I understood what the jaxb binding element **property** actually does, that it uses the name following the naming convention only.